# Reason for triphenyl methane being less acidic than acetylene

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

This question came through answering a [question that talked about the acidic order of four compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149830/finding-order-of-acidic-strength-for-given-compounds?noredirect=1#comment303482_149830).

Upon researching the actual $\mathrm p K_\mathrm a$ values I noticed that even though there was a resonance destabilization of electrons (albeit partial) in triphenyl methane, the $\mathrm p K_\mathrm a$ values of acetylene were less than that of triphenyl methane? I was unable to find a solid reason for why this is the case.

Does anyone in the community have the reason?

Comment: Basically you are seeking confirmation for your answer there, which is unusual. Anyway, I just upvoted it because is it at least in the right direction.

Comment: @Alchimista yeah. I would convert my answer there into a community post if I can get a proper explanation for this one. Since the first part answers the actual question but not the question I pose.

Comment: Triphenyl methane is some kind of propeller shaped, so it has less conjugation, making it very less acidic than what we except.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [@orthocresol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16683/orthocresol), just comparing methane and acetylene shows a difference of $\approx 20$ $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ units and the amount of resonance required to overcome this difference is very high.

Comparing $\mathrm p K_\mathrm a$ of phenol($10.0$) and methanol($15.5$), we see that the presence of one resonating ring only produces a 5.5 $\mathrm p K_\mathrm a$ difference. Resonance in triphenyl system is effectively only one phenyl group at a time due to the steric effects due to the bulkiness of the phenyl groups.